# Differences between Screenlog and Hardcopy on GNU Screen

Tags: logging, terminal, gnu-screen

### Introduction

I'm new using `GNU screen`, and I'm using it mostly because I don't want to lose my work if unexpectedly my SSH connection closes, and also because I want to keep a logfile of every output printed on my terminal (at least some recent tracks)

For SSH stuff, I guess <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>a</kbd> <kbd>d</kbd> to detach and `screen -r` or `screen -r session_name` to re-attach to some session solve all my problems, now I'm trying to understand logging.

I found `screenlog` and `hardcopy` on [this link](http://web.mit.edu/gnu/doc/html/screen_17.html), which basically says:

> **hardcopy** <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>a</kbd> <kbd>h</kbd> Writes out the current display contents to the file `hardcopy.n` in the window's default directory, where `n` is the number of the current window. This either appends or overwrites the file if it exists, as determined by the `hardcopy_append` command.
>
> **log** <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>a</kbd> <kbd>H</kbd> Begins/ends logging of the current window to the file `screenlog.n` in the window's default directory, where n is the number of the current window. If no parameter is given, the logging state is toggled. The session log is appended to the previous contents of the file if it already exists. The current contents and the contents of the scrollback history are not included in the session log. Default is `off`.

---

### Observed Behavior

So, as far as I understood by this and trying to use them, after enabling `screenlog`, it keeps logging everything I write and all the outputs of terminal in that file (which happens to go `$HOME` for me) including those characters to change color like `\033[1;31mm`. If I do `cat screenlog.0`, it crashes sometimes printing the file indefinitely, but ok, I can open it with an editor or in another session...

As for `hardcopy`, apparently it doesn't keep tracking commands, nor colors of outputs, and I don't know if it takes only those few lines that are visible in terminal or everything that happened on that session, could someone clarify this to me?

Finally, I'm opening `screen` on `Terminator` instead of the classical terminal, and even if I open different `screen` sessions on different windows of `Terminator`, all logs go to `screenlog.0` or `hardcopy.0`. In the case of `screenlog`, will it conflict with another process that's being output on other sessions or overwrite it? How can I create different `screenlog.n` files and put them in a directory other than `$HOME`?

---

### Further Considerations

Just to conclude, which one is recommended?
Sorry for this huge question, but I'm trying to write it in a way that it can be useful to clarify details of these logs that I'm having a hard time to find in other places. Feel free to correct me if I said something wrong :)

Comment: If you are just starting to use `screen`, take a look a `tmux` too.

Comment: @WilliamPursell Sometimes I need to use it on a remote server that does not have `tmux` and I don't have root permissions, so I'm stuck with `screen`. By the way, `tmux is simpler/better/safer or something like that?

Comment: Personally, I like the way `tmux` handles the copy buffer.  You can change panes/windows/sessions while keeping different views in different states in the scroll back, which is not possible with screen (or wasn't the last time I looked).

Answer (score 1):

`hardcopy` command does not save character attributes (colors, bold etc.) but, with '-h' argument also saves contents of scrollback buffer.

Destination directory for hardcopy files can be set via `hardcopydir` command; existing files are not moved, and this setting applies to all windows currently open and future ones; directory for log files is "window's default directory" -- this can be changed with `chdir` command; it applies to current window and all future ones.

Log file name pattern can be set via `logfile` command.  All `screen`'s escape sequences should work in the pattern; for example, `logfile screenlog.%Y%m%d.%S.%n`.  However, hardcopy file name pattern is hardcoded.